# Alternative of stopListening() method of SpeechRecognizer class for Android API < 8

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-api-levels

Is there any alternative to `stopListening()` method for API < 8 since this method was included in API level 8?

Answer (score 1):

`SpeechRecognizer` class was added on API 8. So, you can't use it in lower API devices.

Comment: Wasn't this already stated in OP's question though? Because the API isn't available before API 8 they're looking for an alternative.

Comment: @MichaelDodd He's asking specifically about stopListening().

Comment: Michael pointed it correctly. I am looking for an alternative of stopListening() for older versions of Android(or API < 8). I want to know if it is possible to stop speech recognition without using methods included in and after API 8.

Answer (score 0):

The `SpeechRecognizer` class itself was added in API 8.